# Rollover IRA vs traditional IRA (can I make contributions to the rollover IRA?)

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, ira, tax-deduction

I am single and used to contribute to a Roth IRA (my last contribution was years ago), but now my AGI is over the limit to contribute to the Roth.

I have a "rollover IRA" that I opened a few years ago, into which I rolled over a previous 401k's funds. Now, I would like to start contributing to an (any) IRA again, so I think I would need to open a traditional IRA. I cannot take a pre-tax deduction to any IRA contribution since my AGI is high.

Is there any difference between the rollover IRA and the traditional IRA? I would prefer not to have to open yet another account, so adding my yearly ~$5500 to the rollover IRA would be great.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are planning on making a non-deductible Traditional IRA contribution? And not doing an immediate Roth conversion because of the existing pre-tax IRA money?

Comment: @CraigW: "And not doing an immediate Roth conversion because of the existing pre-tax IRA money?" From my understanding, doing a conversion to Roth is advantageous if your tax rate is expected to be higher in retirement. My current tax rate is extremely high right now, and I expect it will be lower in retirement; thus, I do not want to do a Roth conversion.

Comment: @CraigW: "you are planning on making a non-deductible Traditional IRA contribution?" That's right. I contribute to a 401k at work, and my AGI is over $70K, so I cannot make a deductible traditional IRA contribution. I am following the guidelines at: http://taxes.about.com/od/deductionscredits/qt/traditional_ira.htm

Comment: This is really a separate issue, but note the value of a non-deductible Traditional IRA is quite limited. The tax rate now versus in retirement argument only holds when you are getting a deduction. I would strongly advise you to see if you can "roll-in" your rollover IRA to your current 401(k), then do a backdoor Roth IRA contribution.

Comment: @CraigW: "The tax rate now versus in retirement argument only holds when you are getting a deduction." Can you point me to more info on this subject?

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Non-deductible_traditional_IRA). Especially note the section 'What kind of investments are well suited to a non-deductible traditional IRA?', where it shows it's worse to hold a stock index fund in a non-deductible traditional IRA than a regular taxable account (under their circumstances). If I were you I would put in a decent amount of effort to do a backdoor Roth IRA contribution instead.

Comment: Deductible IRAs are *never* a good thing. Either contribute to deductible IRA and immediately convert to Roth, or don't bother. Capital gains rates are *always* lower than ordinary income rates, so why bother? Invest the same amount (or more...) in an index/target fund for 30 years, and you'll be better off tax-wise.

Comment: @littleadv: "Deductible IRAs are never a good thing." You mean *non-deductible* Traditional IRA?

Comment: Yeah, I meant *non* deductible, of course...:)

Comment: @littleadv: if one buys and sells a lot, then the non-deductible IRA is superior to a regular taxable brokerage account, right? With the former, you pay tax once, at withdrawal at  your income tax rate, and with the latter you'd incur capitol gain tax with ever positive sell.

Comment: Yes, there are some cases where it would be beneficial over a taxable account. The one you mention or if you hold bonds in it, for example. But a Roth is _always_ going to be more useful. You get all the same benefits, plus tax-free distributions.

Comment: If you haven't already, see [this post](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Backdoor_Roth_IRA) about Backdoor Roth IRA contributions. Take special note of the 'Caution' section, as it applies to you.

Comment: @CraigW: I agree that Roth IRA is always more useful than non-deductible Traditional IRA. But in the case where you have deductible money in Traditional IRA, you cannot do backdoor Roth IRA without converting the deductible portion also, incurring tax. You may not be able to rollover it to a 401k because, for example, 1) your 401k may not allow the rollover, or 2) you don't have a 401k, but your spouse does, and the joint income is high enough to not be able deduct Traditional IRA or contribute to Roth IRA.

Comment: @user102008 I pointed out the issue with backdoor Roth IRA contributions in my comment (the 'Caution' section). I think the OP should first figure out if they can roll-in their rollover IRA to their 401(k). If not, there is a question of whether a non-deductible Traditional IRA is worth contributing to. If so, there is the question asked here, which is whether they can just add on to their existing rollover IRA.

Comment: @CraigW: There is much noise in these comments that it paralyzed me with fear and doubt, so I did not make a contribution for 2013. Thanks a lot, jerks. I have no idea why I would want a backdoor Roth (sounds vaguely sexual). So I'm making close to $200K a year, and I have no way to use a Roth since I am over the AGI. I asked a simple question and got a bunch of noise, and now I have no contribution. Great.

Comment: @littleadv: "[Non-]Deductible IRAs are never a good thing. Either contribute to deductible IRA and immediately convert to Roth, or don't bother. Capital gains rates are always lower than ordinary income rates, so why bother? Invest the same amount (or more...) in an index/target fund for 30 years, and you'll be better off tax-wise." This is just **horrible** advice. Do you only invest in index funds and just want to avoid tax? Some of us actually have a backbone and would like to buy and sell, so incurring a one-time income tax rather than multiple cap gains tax is better.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 consider the tax result of nondeductible IRA: you pay *ordinary* tax rate on *all* of your gains. In non-taxable account - you pay ordinary tax rate only on short term gains. Are you expecting to be a day trader in your IRA?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that some rollover IRAs (from a 401k for instance), can in future be rolled into a new employer's like-kind retirement plan.  If you are able to contribute to this IRA in the intermittent time frame, it may no longer qualify for the future rollback because it contains commingled funding.

Comment: The rules requiring such segregation are long past. Your answer is good for receiving company that remains unaware.

Comment: So you are now allowed to comingle rollover and personal IRA funds?  I guess I haven't tried recently.

Answer (score 3):

My rollover IRA custodian emailed me this information a few years ago:

> The IRS now says that a Traditional IRA and a Rollover IRA are the same account and follow the same rules.  This means that you could make a contribution to your Rollover IRA.  The only issue you may run into down the road (and it has nothing to do with the title of the account) is that if you ever want to roll your 401k funds back into a 401k, the plan administrator has the right to deny those funds if you have contributions mixed in with the original 401k funds.  Most will not, but they have the option that they could.  If you have any doubt about this, I would suggest opening a separate Traditional/Rollover IRA to make contributions to.

Answer (score 0):

Rollover IRA is a "marketing term" created by the financial industry. A rollover Ira is a traditional ira. The tax treatment is what matters.

You can "rollover" funds from a 401k into a traditional ira or rollover ira, it makes no difference.

You can contribute to the rollover/traditional ira if you MAGI is to high and just wont be able to claim the deduction. You did get the tax deferred growth. After contributing you may want to consider a roth conversion (consult your tax adviser- This is a gray area form IRS treatment which hasn't been ruled on. ) as you arn't really getting any tax deduction benefit from the traditional ira so you can at least get tax free growth in the roth.